# Looping across time series values in R

Tags: r, loops

I apologize if I have overlooked a solution to this somewhere, but I have spent what seems like an unjustifiable amount of time trying to get a solution to this. I want to manipulate multiple time series values and a solution to the simple task below may help:

```
x1 <- c(1, 11, 21)
y1 <- c(2, 12, 22)
x2 <- c(3, 13, 23)
y2 <- c(4, 14, 24)
x3 <- c(5, 15, 25)
y4 <- c(6, 16, 26)
```

Assume the above values go up to `x60` and `y60`.

```
z1 <- x1 + y1
z2 <- x2 + y2 
z3 <- x3 + y3
```

I need to generate the values `z1`, `z2`... with loops. Something along the lines of:

```
for (i in 1:3){
  obj1= paste0("x",i)
  obj2= paste0("y", i)
  dv<- paste0("z", i)
  assign(dv, obj1 + obj2)
}
```

(ofcourse this doesn't run). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mget` to retrieve the 'x' object values into a `list` and likewise the `y` object values, then loop over the corresponding `list` with `Map` and add them (`+`) and return a `list`.  If we need to create 'z' objects in the global env (not recommended), set the names of the output list with 'z1', 'z2', etc and then use `list2env`

```
lst1 <- Map(`+`, mget(ls(pattern = "^x\\d+$")),
                 mget(ls(pattern = "^y\\d+$")))
names(lst1) <- paste0("z", seq_along(lst1))
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

NOTE: Here we used `Map` as the lengths can also be different for each of the vector objects

---

The `for` loop didn't run because the operator (`+`) is applied on the object name strings and not the value.  We can use `get` here

```
for (i in 1:3){
  obj1= paste0("x",i)
  obj2= paste0("y", i)
  dv<- paste0("z", i)
  assign(dv, get(obj1) + get(obj2))
}
```

---

For the edited case, we may do

```
fmla <- paste0(paste0("psr_", 1:60), "~", paste0("unemp_", 1:60))
lapply(fmla, function(fml) td(as.formula(fml), "average"))
```

Comment: That works but maybe I oversimplified it in the example, what I need is to iterate: `psr<- td(psr_1 ~ unemp_1, "average")` 60 times where `psr` `psr_1` and `unemp_1` go up to `psr` `psr_60` and `unemp_60`. Any way to create a loop around it?

Comment: @Pingu try the update

Answer (score 0):

In general one does not use individual variables but rather collects them
into data frames, matrices or other structures.  Here we put the x variables into X, the y variables into Y and  the sums into Z.

```
X <- as.data.frame(mget(ls(pattern = "^x\\d+$")))
Y <- as.data.frame(mget(ls(pattern = "^y\\d+$")))
Z <- X + Y
names(Z) <- sub(".", "z", names(Z))

Z
##   z1 z2 z3
## 1  3  7 11
## 2 23 27 31
## 3 43 47 51

Z[[2]]  # get z2
## [1]  7 27 47

Z$z2 # same
## [1]  7 27 47
```